# Escurecer background com texto sobre imagem

Tags: html, css

Existe alguma maneira de escurecer uma imagem background sem afetar o texto que está sobre ela?

```css
.slider-principal{
 content:'\A';
    top:0; left:0;
    opacity: 0.8;

}

.slider-principal p{
 color: #fff;
 bottom: 0;  
   left: 10px;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: "Myriad Pro";
   z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div style=" background-image: url('/upload/exemplo.jpeg; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%;" class="slider-principal"  >
   <p>Titulo</p>
   <p>Descrição da Imagem</p>
</div>
```

Neste caso, o parágrafo e a imagem ficam opacas, preciso que apenas a imagem fique, para que o texto fique nítido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar um pseudo-elemento `:after` ou `:before` e utilizá-lo como uma camada a frente do background e atrás do texto.
Pra isso você precisa colocar um `position:relative` na `div` principal e utilizar `z-index` para definir qual elemento ficará a frente.

[Segue um fiddle de exemplo.](https://jsfiddle.net/8jmm82q8/)

Comment: Obrigada @Mauro era exatamente o que precisava.